# ReactJs - Display components around a component

Tags: css, reactjs, html

I want to display a specific number of components around a component. How can I do that? :)

With this implementation, I draw 8 Patrat component

```
{Array.from(Array(8)).map((item, index) =>
    (<Patrat key={index}/>)
)}
```

I want to display these 8 Patrat around a circle which is also a component.

Comment: What do you mean by "around"?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jxuc4gas/?fbclid=IwAR31Ua1ku2tnsrnQuno4n4rGwuwJkBED_xXOd8NDsCTTKXifFSLHkxqcpZs OR http://bl.ocks.org/bycoffe/3404776?fbclid=IwAR3mzRJMlZnyz13dTKwnIII2pOX2b4blqry0qMxVfDi_Bpg70Is5EOcP6VM

Comment: You could make the circle responsible for positioning the elements, then have Patrats as children of circle (`Circle > div.circle_element_position > Patrat`) or if Patrats will change depending on the parent component, you could use same logic but use renderProps for Patrats (`Circle > div.circle_element_position > props.renderPatrat(index)`) https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

Comment: Ok, in Circle component I can draw the Patrat components and pass the number of Patrats through props. But how can I draw Patrat component around the Circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Understanding the issue and what you want here is the final solution

You can also create function which can dynamically create position and pass it to the Child components

[Here is complete code resource link (Click Here)](https://codesandbox.io/s/mq845z5n9p)

Also your can experiment with some comment line in code link given above

Comment: Circle is the parent component and Patrat is the child component. Circle pass to the Patrat the number of the Patrats that can be drown and it is dorwn, but not around the circle

Comment: so with in circle parent get the size and based on data generate the position and then pass it to child. if you are not able to do please share repo link to give you some example

Comment: https://github.com/LarisPopa/Notice/blob/master/Frontend/src/components/GuestsPage.js, here is my repo, in GuestsPage.js I am drawing the Circle and Patrat components. Can we have a discussion on fb or something?

Comment: https://codepen.io/dwarka/pen/XGeGOM  : please try it with some css trick

Comment: I have a local implementation, in Guestspage.js I have a Circle component that pass through props to the Patrat numberPeople = {table.number_of_people} which means number of Patrat that should be displayed

Comment: Please give me your facebook account to discuss more or skype ID. I am able to have the discussion in 1 hour. It is ok for you?

Comment: Your example, https://codepen.io/dwarka/pen/XGeGOM with html and css only should be ok, I will try today

Comment: Ok, I will add you in 1-2 hours. Is it ok?

Comment: it is fine to me

Comment: Did you able to figure it out

Comment: Yes, I have a simple implementation by handcoded position for each Patrat around the table, but it's not exactly what I want, I want to display the Patrat component dynamically, so when I have 3 Patrats, I want to show more space between them, if I have 8 Patrats I want to show a little bit space between them, see exemple: https://codepen.io/dbpas/pen/LGudb?fbclid=IwAR3peRMspJKcL0W-xYzxzkX77MQo31ekQ3xcfvjoYy4JGvCDrgB3xhK-IMo

Comment: If you have 3 Patrats want more space or constant space. can you explain more

Comment: Give me something to share with you some pictures. I added you on Skype yesterday

Answer (score 0):

You could create a recursive loop where you create a new `Patrat` component with the recursive call as `children` to it.

**Example**

```js
function Patrat({ children }) {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        paddingLeft: 10,
        backgroundColor: "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const content = (function patratLoop(num) {
    if (num === 0) {
      return <div> Foo </div>;
    }
    return <Patrat>{patratLoop(--num)}</Patrat>;
  })(8);

  return content;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the circle responsible for positioning the elements, then have Patrats as children of circle (`Circle > div.circle_element_position > Patrat`) or if Patrats will change depending on the parent component, you could use same logic but use [renderProps](http://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) for Patrats (`Circle > div.circle_element_position > props.renderPatrat(index)`)

It would look more or less like this:

```
function Partat()  {
   return <div>1</div>
}

function calculatePositions(numberOfPatrats) {
     //your implementation
}

function Circle ({numberOfPatrats}) {
       let positions = calculatePositions(numberOfPatrats);

       return <div className="circle">
            {positions.map(
                (position, index) => <div style={position} key={index}><Partat /></div>
            )}
       </div>
}
```

To place Parats on the positions you want you just need to implement calculatePositions, which will be similar to what you had in your jsfiddle example.